# How to modify this code for calculation seasonal values for each year (not all years)

Tags: matlab

I have a `1x3` cell contains three `360x3` tables. For every table, I wanted to calculate the average of `rrr24` for each season and write them on the 5th column. For example:
[look at this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyIwo.png)

I have a code as you can see below, but it calculates the average of each season for all 30 years (not yearly), and didn't write averages on the 5th column too. 
**As a result, I would like just a new `1x3` cell with tables that have the 5th column as I described above.**

```
    meanTableDataArray = cell(length(CELL),4);
for j = 1:length(CELL)
    sampleTableData = CELL{j};
    sampleTableData.month = month(sampleTableData.dates);
    sampleTableData.seasons = floor(sampleTableData.month ./3);
    sampleTableData.seasons(sampleTableData.seasons ==4 ) = 0;
    sampleTableData.seasons = categorical(sampleTableData.seasons, [0 1 2 3], ["Spr", "Sum", "Aut", "Win"]);
    [group, mean_table] = findgroups(sampleTableData(:, 'seasons'));
    mean_table.rrr24 = splitapply(@mean, sampleTableData.rrr24, group);
    for k = 1:4
        meanTableDataArray{j,k} = mean_table(k,:); % extracts as a table
    end
end
```

[Here is my cell](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1o8Wl-k_hI2wC8HdcbTIHVzyMt0gttroO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you need is to group the data using season index, and then use accumarray to get the sum and then take average.

```
data=[0.2, 0.9, 10, 12, 8, 0.9, 10];
mon= [1,1,2,4,6,7,10];
seasons=floor((mon-eps)/3)+1;

accumarray(seasons,data)                       % this gives you the total
accumarray(seasons(:),ones(size(seasons(:))))  % this gives you the count
                                               % below gives you average
accumarray(seasons(:),data(:))./accumarray(seasons(:),ones(size(seasons(:))))
```